# Нужен код желательно на С

Tags: c

Написать функцию, которая принимает четыре указатели на действительные переменные и заменяет значение
первой из них на сумму третьей и четвертой, а значение третьей - на сумму первой и второй.

Comment: И с чем возникли трудности?

Comment: Я начинающий програмист и не понимаю указатели, по этому прошу помощь, хотя б с чего начать

Comment: С чтения книжек и конспектов. Судя по вопросу вы не "начинающий программист", а студент на пороге сессии.

Comment: Да я студент, но мы учим Python, а С я решил учить для себя

Comment: И что? В той книжке нет определения указателя? Где-то на первых 10 страницах

Comment: Если было в книжке тогда бы не спрашивал, или на ютубе понятней

Comment: Тогда, наверное, нужно было в вопросе писать не текст задачи, а вызвавшее трудности определение с детальным описанием, что именно не понятно. Потому, что при получении ответа понятнее не станет

Comment: Я первый раз на stackoverflow, и еще толком не знаю что и как, поэтому решил задать вопрос который возник и это была задача которую не могу решить потому что  не знаю с чего начать

Comment: Ну тогда надо поправить вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Написать функцию, которая принимает четыре указатели на действительные
>   переменные и заменяет значение первой из них на сумму третьей и
>   четвертой, а значение третьей - на сумму первой и второй.

Ну вот, что-то в этом роде наверное:

```
void fun(float* a1,float* a2,float* a3,float* a4){

float aa=*a1;

*a1=(*a3)+(*a4);
*a3=aa+(*a2);

}
```